# Adsense API Reporting -- Timely Updates

Tags: adsense-api

Google Analytics provides adsense data after 24 hours. I assume that is to process atomic events into reports.

It appears Google Adsense Website updates their reports every hour, but numbers can change days or even weeks after they are posted. I assume that's for fraud prevention.

My question is if Google Adsense API provides updates every hour, or every 24 hours. Here is example python code:

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-adsense-examples/blob/master/python/v1.4/generate_report.py

```
service, flags = sample_tools.init(
  argv, 'adsense', 'v1.4', __doc__, __file__, parents=[argparser],
  scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense.readonly')
```

I tried looking through their docs and couldn't find a reporting update interval:

https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adsense API updates quickly, almost in real time.